# Increasing memory usage in sqlite3?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I've written a console app which receives events via boost::interprocess memory and dumps the info into an sqlite3 database. While running the app I've noticed that, in the Windows task manager, the memory usage was cyclically increasing every... 30s-1min. This led me to believe that the problem lies within the main loop in which I execute my SQL. I've added some monitoring and apparently the sqlite3_memory_usage returns increasing results every couple loop iterations.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? Am I missing something I should de-allocate ?

Here  are 2 strings I use to generate SQL

```
    const std::string sql_insert =
      "INSERT INTO EventsLog "
      "(Sec, uSec, DeviceId, PmuId, EventId, Error, Msg) "
      "VALUES (%ld, %ld, %ld, %d, %ld, %d, %Q)";

    const std::string sql_create =
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EventsLog("
      "Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
      "Sec INTEGER NOT NULL, "
      "uSec INTEGER NOT NULL, "
      "DeviceId INTEGER NOT NULL, "
      "PmuId INTEGER NOT NULL, "
      "EventId INTEGER NOT NULL, "
      "Error INTEGER NOT NULL, "
      "Msg TEXT"
      ")";
```

In here, I generate the SQL INSERT command

```
std::string construct_sql_query
    (const ELMessageData & data)
    {
      std::string query = "";

      ptime jan1st1970 = ptime(date(1970,1,1));
      ptime now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
      time_duration delta = now - jan1st1970;
      TimeVal time((uint32)delta.total_seconds(),
                   (uint32)now.time_of_day().fractional_seconds());

      char * const sql = sqlite3_mprintf(sql_insert.c_str(),
                                         time.tv_sec,
                                         time.tv_usec,
                                         data.getDeviceId(),
                                         data.getPmuId(),
                                         data.getEventId(),
                                         (data.getIsError() ? 1 : 0),
                                          data.getExMsg().c_str());
      if(sql == NULL)
        post_event(EvIOError("Failed to create the SQL command",
                             "StLoggingEvents::_construct_sql_query"));

      query = std::string(sql);
      sqlite3_free(sql);

      return query;
    } // construct_sql_query
```

Here's the main loop in which I execute the INSERT commands

```
 while(true)
    {
      m_exchange_obj->wait(); // wait for the semaphore to be raised
  const std::string sql = construct_sql_query
    (m_exchange_obj->receive());

  char ** err = NULL;

  const int rc = sqlite3_exec(m_db_handle,
                              sql.c_str(),
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              err);
  sqlite3_free(err);

  if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
  {
    LERR_ << "Error while inserting into the database";
    LERR_ << "Last SQL Query : ";
    LERR_ << sql;
  }
  else
  {
    LDBG_ << "Event logged...";
    LDBG_ << "Sqlite3 memory usage : "
          << sqlite3_memory_used();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Looking at the code I can't see anything wrong... It has to be related to something else (receiving events, maybe, the receive() call allocating memory that's not freed, etc.)

Comment: I forgot to mention, too, that maybe sqlite can have some internal storage that uses discretionary to a maximum before releasing internal memory... It may come to a maximum and stay stable afterwards.

Comment: Is there a way to force an internal release ?

Comment: just found sqlite3_memory_release(int). No effect, memory_used still returns incrementing results.

Comment: I've just used sqlite3_status(0 /*0 is for mem usage*/, &current, &highwater, false)
results were interesting. every couple times the loop iterates, both the current and highwater counters increase... honestly I don't know what to think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second the suggestion of trying this under valgrind. You may also want to look at google's tcmalloc replacement... It can print pretty graphs showing you all your leaks... That said, I hope you get the answer for this... I plan on using SQLite in an upcoming project...

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to run valgrind on Windows

Comment: You know, if you could separate the sqlite code out, you can probably pretty easily try this on a Linux VM under valgrind... :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining your memory usage?  You may not have a real leak.

If you are on a windows system and using visual studio, compile in debug mode and use the memory debugging macros to find your leaks.

If you are on a unix based system, try valgrind / memcheck.

I think OS X's xcode also detects leaks too.

Comment: I'm on windows. I'm determining my memory usage by watching the task manager + monitoring a log output which logs the value from sqlite3_memory_used(). That forementioned value keeps increasing.

I've used sqlite3_status(), and for some reason both the current and highwater values for memory usage keep increasing. I'm not really sure what's going on

Comment: What compiler are you using?  The MS runtime library macros are great if you are compiling with VS.  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3.aspx

The problem with using task manager is that the it isn't very accurate.  You really need to find out from the memory allocator what is going on.  WinDbg also does some excellent leak detection too.